# Is there a way to detect movement on "screens" using python?

Tags: python, detection

For example, if I'm in some game and I want to check whether I'm moving or not. So, for that, is there a way to detect the motion of the player using python? Please Suggest some ideas if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, you should really give a clear example of the environment. Is this for Linux? Windows? What does movement mean? Just something happening in single application? Which application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `pynput`

```py
from pynput.mouse import Controller

mouse = Controller()

before = mouse.position

while True:
    current = mouse.position
    if before != current:
        print('Movement detected')
    before = current
```

The variable `before` references to the movement that's been before the current loop, and I basically check if the current position is different than it was the iteration before

You can also check for the keyboard presses

[pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)
[docs](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answering to your comment, it's also possible, this time using `pyautogui`

```py
import pyautogui

before = pyautogui.screenshot()

while True:
    current = pyautogui.screenshot()
    if before != current:
        print('Screen is different')
    before = current
```

[pypi](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding with an answer. I tried this code, but it just keeps displaying the output of movement detected. And overall, I think the code is designed to detect mouse movements I suppose. (Please tell me if I am wrong)

Comment: It is, it's printing `Movement detected` whenever you move your mouse

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question. My question was basically to find if there was any movement on-screen. For example, if something moves on the screen, like any object in-game, I want to detect if it can move.

As an example, if we can check each frame is different than the other.

Comment: check the edit.

Comment: Hey, yes, it works! Thanks a lot.